# how to drop into telerik RadTreeview from telerik RadFileExplorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview

I have asp.net ajax website and those 2 controls. I'd like to drop file name from FileExplorer into treeview. Event is firing up but somehow no information about destination. Looks like get_htmlElement is not present e.g.

```
 window.onFileExplorerMove = function (sender, args) {
        //get the html element on which the node is dropped
        var target = args.get_htmlElement; //null
}
```

for treeview event is like this:

```
 protected void RadTreeView1_NodeDrop(object sender, RadTreeNodeDragDropEventArgs e)
    {..}
```

but how would be for FileExplorer drop or move?

I can do it from e.g listbox etc but FileExplorer gives me hard time. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out:

```
protected void RadFileExplorer1_ItemMove(object sender, RadFileExplorerEventArgs e)
    {
        string command = e.Command;
        if (e.Command == "MoveFile") 
        {
            //etc
        }
   }
```